# Pointing EC2 instance to a custom DNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have been trying to follow this tutorial but it is more complex than it needs to be I hope because I can assign tag names manually and I can do the route53 stuff manually. 
https://www.esentri.com/auto-register-ec2-instance-in-aws-route-53/

What I have so far is I have created a PUBLIC hosted zone. "myzoneabc.com"  This was created indirectly after I created my registered domain in Route53.

I then launched an EC2 instance and took its AWS assigned DNS name and created a CNAME record as follows

server.myzoneabc.com  CNAME   ec2-35-177-xxx-xxx.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com

I can RDP onto server with DNS = server.myzoneabc.com  with no problem.
Problem with this is when I restart my EC2 then the DNS which I entered in my route53 record above is no longer valid because it will have been modified after a stop/start of my EC2 instance.
My EC2 instance is only created once and either in a running or stopped state, it is never terminated. 
So question is ,  is there any way to have route53 point a DNS recore like server.myzoneabc.com  at my EC2 instance without using the DNS that Amazon assigns it which is always different.  Thats what I think these EC2 instance tags are doing in the tutorial link posted above.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to update your DNS provider to use the NS records of your hosted zone. Only creating the Hosted Zone, will not tell anyone on the internet to use it.

Follow the Developer Guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingNewSubdomain.html